Does adding too much node make rendering slower?
I added a lot of node on this one tutorial that I have been following and the render keeps on getting slower and slower. In the end, I have to restart the app because the render just wouldn't start.

This is a pointless question that has the answer in itself. "Too much" - what is it too much for? For the render times to be fast? It's pretty much the same as asking "Does render time increase when I add so many nodes so that render time increases?" You already know the answer and demonstrate it clearly in the question, so what's the point of this? Maybe you should edit the question and narrow it down to something more specific that you wish to know about the situation so it makes more sense.

Dude, you don't need to get agitated over a question. I was just simply asking because I am new to blender and I don't really understand how nodes work yet.

Not really agitated. Just looking at the question and thinking about how to answer it. It's answered, but that seems pointless, because the answer was already in the question, so maybe there was something else you really don't understand about that situation that I think would make more sense to ask about.  I am not emotional about it, just trying to think logically.
